# Check if given time minus now time is less than 60 minutes using php

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have read a lot here, and tried a lot, but I didn't get it :(

I have:

```
$end = new DateTime('22:00');
$now = new DateTime();

if(($end - $now) < 60)
{
    $bijnaTijd = "bijnaTijdJa";
}
```

I want to see if the difference between the `$end` and the current time is less than `60` minutes. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get timestamp from `DateTime` object using [`getTimestamp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) and compare timestamps with each other.

Note that timestamp is in second so i used `60*60` to converting minutes to seconds.

```
$end = new DateTime('22:00');
$now = new DateTime();

if (($end->getTimestamp() - $now->getTimestamp()) < 60*60){
    // do something
}
```

Also you can dates function instead of `DateTime` class.

```
if (strtotime('22:00') - time() < 60*60){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

please check this code , hope it solve your problem

```
<?php 
$end        = new DateTime('22:00');
$new_end    = strtotime($end->format('Hi')); //convert to string
$end_h      = idate('h', $new_end); //get the hour
$end_h      = str_pad($end_h, 2, 0, STR_PAD_RIGHT);
$end_m      = idate('i', $new_end);
$end_m      = str_pad($end_m, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); //get leading zero for above minutes 10
$time_end   = $end_h.''.$end_m;

$now = new DateTime();
$new_now    = strtotime($now->format('Hi'));
$now_h      = idate('h', $new_now);
$now_h      = str_pad($now_h, 2, 0, STR_PAD_RIGHT);
$now_m      = idate('i', $new_now);
$now_m      = str_pad($now_m, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
$time_now   = $now_h.''.$now_m;


echo ($time_end - $time_now); //get the result do your logic after this code
```